# Algorithm for merging lists of words

Tags: algorithm, sorting, combinations, combinatorics, linguistics

I am working on a project in which I have to combine multiple data sets, i.e. merge semi-similar lists of words. These are words that fit certain meanings of a word. Here's some real data:

```
home[a]: abode|domicile|dwelling|dwelling place|habitation|house|pad|residence
home[a]: abode|element|environment|habitat|habitation|haunt|home ground|range|stamping ground|territory
home[a]: at ease|comfortable|familiar|relaxed
home[a]: available|in|present
home[a]: birthplace|family|fireside|hearth|homestead|home town|household
home[a]: central|domestic|familiar|family|household|inland|internal|local|national|native
home[a]: conversant with|familiar with|knowledgeable|proficient|skilled|well-versed
home[a]: drive home|emphasize|impress upon|make clear|press home
home[a]: entertaining|giving a party|having guests|receiving
home[a]: party|reception|soirée
home[b]: abode|diggings|domicile|dwelling|fireside|habitation|hearth|hearthstone|house|lodging|pad|place|quarters|residence|roof
home[b]: cradle|birthplace|mother country|motherland|-|hometown|country|nativity|old country|roots
home[b]: extended family|household|house|ménage|-|blood|folks|kin|kindred|kinfolk|kinfolks|kinsfolk|kith|brood|nuclear family|clan|community
home[b]: fatherland|country|homeland|mother country|motherland|sod|-|old country|community|neighborhood
home[b]: habitat|niche|range|territory|-|element|environment|environs|haunt|locality|milieu|neighborhood|setting|surroundings
home[c]: abode|habitat|natural habitat|environment|natural element|natural territory|original habitation|home ground|stamping ground|haunt|domain
home[c]: domestic|internal|interior|local|national|native
home[c]: family|family background|family circle|household
home[c]: home town|birthplace|homeland|native land|fatherland|motherland|mother country|country of origin
home[c]: homegrown|homemade|homespun
home[c]: house|abode|domicile|residence|dwelling|dwelling place|habitation
home[c]: house|apartment|condominium|bungalow|cottage
home[c]: residential home|institution|shelter|refuge|hostel|hospice|retirement home|nursing home|rest home|convalescent home|convalescent hospital|children's home
home[d]: domestic|internal|local|national|interior
home[d]: homemade|homegrown|family
home[d]: institution|nursing home|retirement home|rest home|children's home|hospice|shelter|refuge|retreat|asylum|hostel|halfway house
home[d]: origin|source|cradle|fount|fountainhead
home[d]: residence|place of residence|house|apartment|flat|bungalow|cottage|accommodations|property|quarters|rooms|lodgings|a roof over one's head|address|place
home[e]: domestic|internal|local|national|interior
home[e]: homemade|homegrown|family
home[e]: institution|nursing home|retirement home|rest home|children's home|hospice|shelter|refuge|retreat|asylum|hostel|halfway house
home[e]: origin|source|cradle|fount|fountainhead
home[e]: residence|place of residence|house|apartment|flat|bungalow|cottage|accommodations|property|quarters|rooms|lodgings|a roof over one's head|address|place|pad|digs|hearth|nest|domicile|abode|dwelling|dwelling place|habitation
home[f]: home base or origin birthplace|native land|fatherland|habitat
home[f]: residence house|domicile|abode|habitation|dwelling|quarters|place|castle|lodging|roost|diggings|pad
```

*There is zero significance to the syntax.*

Notice how some lists are pretty similar. e.g, these two:

```
home[c]: homegrown|homemade|homespun
home[d]: homemade|homegrown|family
```

The goal is to group the essentially similar lists together. I have already solved a problem of stemming (e.g. match "dwelling" and "dwellings"), and I require the greater of a % match (e.g. 50%) or a minimum number of matches (e.g. 3).

However, I have been having problems with the algorithms I have devised. The biggest problem is the large lists tend to eat up the other lists with a snowball effect. I'll end up with 8 lists, and one of the lists has 150+ items.

I'd appreciate any ideas about how to merge these. Intuitively, I think these 36 lists should condense down to around 10. Maybe ideas using a physical model of attraction, or multiple passes. Ideas?

Pseudocode or suggested algorithms are welcome. I code mostly in ruby, but any language is ok. I included the 'sort' tag because I wonder if sorting-type passes would help.

Comment: More clarification needed on when to combine these lists. If the snowball effect is undesireable, mention strict parameters which must be followed by the final result for them to be called a solution.

Comment: This question seems to broad and can collect many different opinions on what should go together and what not. The specs should be clear.

Comment: So your problem is that you are basically doing a bubble or select sort? i.e. passing through each list, comparing each vs. the first, and merging as you go if you meet a merger criterion? What happens next, after a merge? Do you start over or continue?

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the feedback so far. The expected result would be relatively balanced. Not necessarily 1/N of the terms per list, but not 90% in one list and 10 spread over the rest. In the above example, I'd expect "homegrown" and "homemade" to end up in the same list, and for that to stay standalone, not merged with others.

Comment: And yes, @MichaelCodes, I do a simple comparison one by one.